# How to denote that something is a subalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup), for a given group $G$, the relation of its subgroup $H$ to $G$ is usually denoted by $H\le G$ (or $H\lt G$ for a proper subgroup).

What about algebras? What is the most common/usual/accepted way of denoting that $\mathfrak h$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$?

Examples I have encountered:

1. $\mathfrak h-\mathfrak g$
2. $\mathfrak h\,\backslash\, \mathfrak g$
3. $\mathfrak h\le \mathfrak g$

Comment: Have you really encountered those examples?? The first two are extremely unusual and I would be shocked to see them, except perhaps as an informal blackboard shorthand.

Comment: Not in a textbook or publication, rather lecture notes and on blackboards, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the most common way to denote this is to say "$\mathfrak{h}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$" (or perhaps "$\mathfrak{h}\subseteq\mathfrak{g}$ is a subalgebra").  There is not any common special notation for this.

(I would also disagree that subgroups are "usually" denoted with $H\leq G$.  This notation is sometimes used and is widely recognized, but again it is very common to not use any special symbol for this and just write it in words.)